# under what circumstances NewIntArray would return NULL?

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

`jintArray result = env->NewIntArray(count);`

`env->SetIntArrayRegion(result, 0, count, names);`

We have this implementation in our code, but sometimes SetIntArrayRegion will having error as "JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: java_array == null", wondering under what circumstances NewIntArray would return NULL?

We tried following:

- NewIntArray(0)
- NewIntArray(something big)
- env = NULL

All give different messages, cannot repo the original error

Comment: Since you tagged your answer with [android], have you considered reading the Android JNI implementation? It is surprisingly readable.

Comment: The most likely cause is an error in your earlier native code - most likely it's either a missed exception (you *are* checking *every* return value from *every* JNI call in your native code to the JVM for errors *and* checking for pending exceptions from *every* JNI call in your native code to the JVM that can throw an exception, aren't you?) or you did something like pass a JVM object from one JNI invocation to another by caching it in your native code.  But without a complete example, there's no way for anyone else to know.